# how resolve fs.cpSync filter option src attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, node.js-fs

When using filter option in `fs.cpSync` the src attribute gives a abnormal path

```js
fs.cpSync(src, dest, {
    recursive: true,
    filter: (src) => console.log(src), // "\\?\D:\path\to\a\folder"
})
```

How to convert it to normal path like "D:\path\to\a\folder"